# Android applink with sspPattern opens on Browser

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, android-deep-link, android-app-links

I have to open some urls in my app instead of web browsers.

url examples should open in app:

https://www.example.com?deeplink=some

https://www.example.com/?deeplink=some

https://www.example.com/product/glass?deeplink=some

https://www.example.com/product/type/?deeplink=some

url examples should not open in app:

https://www.example.com

https://www.example.com/product

I have managed to handle filtering with **sspPattern** like this:

```
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

      <data android:scheme="https" />
      <data android:sspPattern="//www.example.com/?deeplink=.*" />
      <data android:sspPattern="//www.example.com?deeplink=.*" />
      <data android:sspPattern="//www.example.com/.*?deeplink=.*" />
      <data android:sspPattern="//www.example.com/.*/.*?deeplink=.*" />

    </intent-filter>
```

Also i uploaded the assetlinks.json to the https://www.example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

But still when i click the url, it opens on web browser (chrome).

If I **disable the chrome** and try to click the link, this time opens in my app.

When I try to test by adb without putting my package name, it triggers `com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeTabbedActivity` ,

`adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://www.example.com/glass?deeplink=some"`

When i give my app package name:

`adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://www.example.com/glass?deeplink=some" my.package.name` it opens in my app.

Does anybody have any idea why is it still being caught by chrome even i publish my `assetlinks.json` file and set `android:autoVerify="true"`?

Thanks a lot.